# Change Docker container environment variables like Kitematic but with command line

Tags: docker, environment-variables

The docker GUI tool Kitematic has a panel which allows changing environmental variables for a running container. Upon change (and save), the container restarts with the environmental variables changed.

Is there a way to do this via a command line tool to do the same on a remote server?

I know that the containers can be deleted and re-run with new environmental variables, but that doesn't preserve the contents.

I have other containers which do DNS proxying via the variables, but I'm trying to not recreate a slow starting container.

Comment: I'm now using [Portainer](https://www.portainer.io/) to help (not solve) this need. It allows me to clone a container and modify values before creating the clone.